# Problems with compiling Open Surge in Linux Mint 17 x86_64: skipping incompatible libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, allegro, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17 x86_64 and I am getting the following warnings while compiling the modified library Alfont for open source game Open Surge (based on Allegro library):

```
danil@linuxmint ~/opensnc-code-opensurge/alfont $ gcc -fPIC -DPIC -O2 -m32 -Iinclude `freetype-config --cflags` -o src/alfont.o -c src/alfont.csrc/alfont.c: In function ‘alfont_ugetx’:
src/alfont.c:3765:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    ugetxc((char**)s);
    ^
src/alfont.c:3765:4: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:3767:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc((char**)s);
  ^
src/alfont.c:3767:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:3771:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc(&lpszWS);
  ^
src/alfont.c:3771:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:3773:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc(&lpszWS);
  ^
src/alfont.c:3773:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:3818:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc((char**)s);
  ^
src/alfont.c:3818:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:3820:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc((char**)s);
  ^
src/alfont.c:3820:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c: In function ‘alfont_ugetxc’:
src/alfont.c:4087:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc(&lpszWS);
  ^
src/alfont.c:4087:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
src/alfont.c:4089:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ugetxc’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  ugetxc(&lpszWS);
  ^
src/alfont.c:4089:2: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

I think that these problems are not very serious. But the next step, I get the following errors:

```
danil@linuxmint ~/opensnc-code-opensurge/alfont $ gcc -O2 -m32 -shared -Wl,-soname,libalfont.so.2 -o libalfont.so.2.0.9 src/alfont.o `freetype-config --libs` `allegro-config --libs |sed 's/-lalleg_unsharable//'`
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so when searching for -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.a when searching for -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so when searching for -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.a when searching for -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a when searching for -lz
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so when searching for -lpng12
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.a when searching for -lpng12
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so when searching for -lpng12
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.a when searching for -lpng12
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng12
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liballeg.so when searching for -lalleg
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liballeg.so when searching for -lalleg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lalleg
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please tell me how to fix these errors with incompatible libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to compile a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit system.

One solution might be to compile a 64 bit binary instead, that one would be able to use your native 64 bit libraries.

If you for some reason need to compile this as a 32 bit binary you will have to make sure that you install all needed 32 bit libraries. You will also have to make sure that your freetype-config and allegro-config programs point to your 32 bit versions of the libraries.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the flag *-m32* to *-m64* in commands which I used to compile project, and it works!